# Laravel - Where Condition on Multiple Database

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

I'm using laravel with multiple DB connection. Oracle and PostgreSQL. I can do query from both of instance.
But the problem is I have to look inside my Oracle DB **WHERE NOT EXISTS** on my postgreSQL.
This is my current Query :

```
DB::connection('ora')->table('ora_purch')
            ->whereExists(function($query)
            {
                $query->select(DB::connection('pgs')->raw(1))
                      ->from('pg_purch')
                      ->whereRaw('ora_purch.id = pg_purch.id');
            })
            ->get();
```

From this query, I get error "database pg_purch is not exists". It's just like laravel reads pg_purch as an oracle instance.

I also do simulation with the same query and the same instance (multiple database on postgreSQL only), the query is fine and produces correct data.

Is it possible to makes the laravel reads pg_purch refer to the connection?
Or maybe i've missing something?
Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code generates query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ora_purch WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_purch WHERE ora_purch.id = pg_purch.id);
```

And make it with "ora" connection, ignoring "pgs" connection.

You can't use multiple connections inside one query.

Try to split them:

```
$ids = DB::connection('pgs')->from('pg_purch')->pluck('id');

$result = DB::connection('ora')->from('ora_purch')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the accepted answer you may want to change the `from()` method to `table()` as it may generate errors in the Laravel latest version. Below is the adjusted query.

```
$ids = DB::connection('pgs')->table('pg_purch')->pluck('id');

$result = DB::connection('ora')->table('ora_purch')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```